# Discontinuous Galerkin for flow through porous media

Tags: discontinuous-galerkin

I am struggling with DG methods for 2 phase flow through porous media. I managed to get the global pressure, total flux equations to work with an unconditionally stable mixed FE DG formulation as described here:
http://math.aalto.fi/reports/a531.ps

but the saturation equation is giving me problems. Basically I tried LDG and IP and both gave pretty weird unphysical results.

Does anyone have any good references for DG with flow through porous media? I found at least one good compositional flow paper, but not much about blackoil models.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I probably should add that I am writing the code with FEniCS and CBCPDESys. So far it has saved me years in development time.

Comment: I really want to learn something about DG. Unfortunately, I didn't have the time to do it. I think http://www.nudg.org might be a good reference. If you find s.th. there, let us know.

Comment: Thank you sir. I think I have to go back to the drawing board on this one. There appears to be a lot of references in papers that partially describe what needs to be done, and rapid implementation in FEniCS shows some promise. I think I found a way to make it work.